# MVC 6 - Web API 2.0 white space on parameter URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to do a search on my Web API URL, as follows:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/trips/World Trip/stops
```

In this case, "World Trip" is the word. But when the call arrives on the server, it arrives as follows:

[image]

"`World%20Trip`" with code `%20` to replace the empty space!

IS there some setting that has to be made to prevent substituting the space with code? I remember `<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />` in previous versions.

I do not want to use any method for conversion within the server: Such as `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode()`.

My Data Annotation route:

```
[Route("api/trips/{tripName}/stops")]
```

My StopController.cs

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Framework.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using TheWorld.Models;
using TheWorld.ViewModels;

namespace TheWorld.Controllers.Api
{
    [Route("api/trips/{tripName}/stops")]

    public class StopController : Controller
    {
        private ILogger<StopController> _logger;
        private IWorldRepository _repository;

        public StopController(IWorldRepository repository, ILogger<StopController> logger)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet("")]
        public JsonResult Get(string tripName)
        {
            try
            {
                var results = _repository.GetTripByName(tripName);

                if (results == null)
                {
                    return Json(null);
                }

                return Json(Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<StopViewModel>>(results.Stops.OrderBy(s => s.Order)));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Failed to get stops for trip {tripName}", ex);
                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                return Json("Error occurred finding trip name");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that should be handled by default, like in asp.net mvc 4.6. I would suggest logging an issue on Github for it

Comment: Here. Let me give you the link to issue the bug: https://github.com/aspnet/mvc/issues

Comment: Have you notice in your url space already there , better to share your code,.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(yourstring)` and you will have a more secure application.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem when walking through the pluralsight tutorial *"Building a Web App with ASP.net 5, MVC 6, EF7 and AngularJS"*.

I solved the issue by using the code below,

```
tripName = WebUtility.UrlDecode(tripName);
```

This appears to be a bug in beta-8. Upgrade to rc1 and your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with user1919597 an upgrade all your packages and install the newest ASP version to rc1-update1 (this is the newest as of 11/30 up to this post date). See [Shawn's Blog Post to perform all the updates you will need](http://wildermuth.com/2015/11/18/Upgrading_ASP_NET_5_Beta_8_to_RC1)

Afterwards, you can test that the code is picking up the tripName in the URL bypassing it into the error message as follows

```
return Json($"Error occurred finding trip name {tripName}");
```

If the code returns an error it will pass in the tripName string from the url - for example: http://localhost:5151/api/trips/World%20Trip/stops  will return "Error occurred finding trip name World Trip".

Now if your only getting an error message, instead of data, then something else may be going on...which happens to be the issue I am currently facing with this part of the course...its been 2 days of searching with no true fix...

All and All - Start with updating everything according to Shawn's Blog and then test this out again. Good Luck and I am interested to know how it turns out.